# OleDbConnectionStringBuilder returning value incompatible with OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, .net, oledbconnection, oledbexception

We have run into an unexpected exception thrown when opening a `OleDbConnection` created from the return value of the `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString` property. Were using the `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to update any relative `DataSource` paths to absolute paths.

We get an `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` exception when we call `OleDbConnection.Open` and the message states:
**"Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification."**.

The code is:

```
    var oleDBbuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);

    oleDBbuilder.DataSource = ResolveDataSourcePath(oleDBbuilder.DataSource);

    m_pOleDb = new OleDbConnection(oleDBbuilder.ConnectionString);
    m_pOleDb.Open(); // <-- Throws exception here
```

We have had no issue with this until we attempted to process a connect string which contained the value `Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;`. The value returned by `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString` property returns the property with the its value quoted. e.g:

This connection string (variable 'connectString'):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\SomePath\@Some Database.mdb;Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=False
```

becomes (OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString):

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="c:\SomePath\Some Database.mdb";Persist Security Info=False;Mode="ReadWrite|Share Deny None"
```

The `Mode` value without quotes works without error!

I have a couple of questions:

- Is this by design? Why does it return an incompatible value?
- How can I work around this without duplicating the job of `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: Can you give the values for `pszConnectString` and `oleDBbuilder.Provider`?

Comment: They are included near the bottom of the question. Only the path was slightly modified, the rest was copied straight from debugger.

Comment: I've updated question in hopes of making things clearer regarding 'pszConnectString' (now 'connectString').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a real answer, just a work around.

Before using oleDBbuilder.ConnectionString you can remove the quotes with a regex like this:

```
m_pOleDb = new OleDbConnection(Regex.Replace(oleDBbuilder.ConnectionString, @"(?<=mode=)((?<quote>""|')?(?<inner>[^;]+?)\k<quote>)", "${inner}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

instead of

```
m_pOleDb = new OleDbConnection(oleDBbuilder.ConnectionString);
```

Another option, if you are responsible for the original connection string, would be to replace the spaces in "Share Deny None" with a placeholder like "Share###Deny###None" before committing it to oleDBbuilder. At the end before using oleDBbuilder.ConnectionString this replacement must be undone again.

To answer your first question ("Is this by design?") I can only speculate. To me it looks more like careless programming. Net programmers ignored the fact that ADODB.ConnectionModeEnum has a kind of flags attribute, so that multiple values can be added with Or.

**Edit**

First: For me it looks like a misconception that keys with spaces inside are quoted. This is only necessary for keys with leading or trailing spaces.

Second: I did some tests. This works with Provider=VFPOLEDB.1 and Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0:

```
Mode=ReadWrite|Share Deny None
Mode=ReadWrite|"Share Deny None"
```

This doesn't work:

```
Mode="ReadWrite|Share Deny None"
Mode="ReadWrite"|"Share Deny None"
```

Comment: Misconception by the implementer?

Comment: I've accepted this answer as the second suggestion is what was eventually implemented by another developer. However I probably now think it would be simpler/easier just to remove the argument then re-add to result of calling 'ConnectString'.

Comment: @karmasponge First: misconception by MS is what I thought about. Second: I do agree, ConnectionStringBuilder isn't a good tool to make programmers live easier.